# How to check the dictionary key-value is present in another function using python-2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am using python-2.7 and working on retrieval of dictionary's key-value from another function.

My code-

```
function1(self):
self.dict1 = {'Old_link':id} # dict1 contains many such key-value wherein key=link,value=id
....#some
....#code

function2(self):
....#some
....#code
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")  #creates a soup
self.tag1 = soup.findAll("div","class_name")
for i in self.tag1:
    self.Old_link = i.find('a').get('href')
try: 
    #insert into table query
    self.id = cursor.lastrowid
    self.dict1['Old_link'] = self.id
except: 
        print(error)


function3(self):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")  #creates a soup
  self.tag = soup.findAll("div","class_name")
  for i in self.tag:
    self.New_link = i.find('a').get('href')
                if self.New_link == any self.dict1.has_key(self.Old_link):
                # get the id and match with other_id
```

How to match New_link with the old one from function1()

I apologize for not asking correctly.

Help /Guidance in any form is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These functions look like methods of a class. You defined New_link and Old_link as attributes of the class so they should be accessible everywhere within the class. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Could you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @wrkyle- I want to match the link(old) from dict1 which I pass to function1 from function2 with link(new) in function3. Also the old_link is a key in dict1.

Comment: Can any one help please- Trying to be more specific here-
`code` 
`def function3():
 some code.....
  if  New_link == any in (dict1.keys()):
    print "True"
    some code.....
  else:
   print "False"`
`code'
with respect to above reference